# Get specific attributes from xml files using c#

Tags: c#, regex, xml

what is the best way to get attributes from xml files ?

I used regex but it's a bit pointless to extract the attributes.

```
<DataPacket Name="(.*)" Value="(.*)" Bit="(.*)"\/>

Group1 = Name
Group2 = Value
Group3 = Bit
```

```
         <HeaderPacket Name="#Header">
            <DataPacket Name="A" Value="1" Bit="7"/>
            <DataPacket Name="B" Value="2" Bit="7"/>            
         </HeaderPacket>
         <HeaderPacket Name="1">
            <DataPacket Name="C" Value="17" Bit="16"/>
            <DataPacket Name="L" Value="22" Bit="8"/> 
         </HeaderPacket>
```

Output I want to get:

Group1:

```
Header:
A 1 7
B 2 7
```

Group2:

```
1:
C 17 16
L 22 8
```

Comment: 1: don't use regex. 2: Use something like `XmlDocument`.

Comment: @Llama Ok, thanks. Should I extract each element or can I get as block elements ?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [`XPathNavigator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator?view=net-6.0) for this in the past. Microsoft has a nice guide on how to use it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/xml-xpathnavigator

Comment: thanks Chris. Any sample code for my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a thousand ways to skin this cat but something like this will do what you want.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

    var xml = "<Root><HeaderPacket Name=\"#Header\"><DataPacket Name=\"A\" Value=\"1\" Bit=\"7\"/><DataPacket Name=\"B\" Value=\"2\" Bit=\"7\"/></HeaderPacket><HeaderPacket Name=\"1\"><DataPacket Name=\"C\" Value=\"17\" Bit=\"16\"/><DataPacket Name=\"L\" Value=\"22\" Bit=\"8\"/></HeaderPacket></Root>";
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

    foreach (XmlNode headerPacket in xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//HeaderPacket"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{headerPacket.Attributes["Name"].Value}:");

        foreach (XmlNode dataPacket in headerPacket.ChildNodes)
        { 
            foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in dataPacket.Attributes)
                Console.Write($"{attribute.Value} ");

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

... take note that I've added the `<Root>` element to ensure it loads correctly and as for the output, that can be anything you want, I've tried to make it like you have in your question.

[image: Debugger]

This shows you how you can traverse and extract XML data in C# though.